# When saving excel file, numbers are converted to date

Tags: excel

I have a file (only one) with some columns with integer numbers. When I change and save file, those columns are automaticaly converted in dates. Does anyone knows how can i prevent this? Thank You!

Comment: No. I'm saving in the same format, and don't have any code running.

Comment: The integer numbers are not results of calculations. Excel version is 2007. And the file always work well. But now, every time I change the contents, save and close, when I open again, the integers are date formated!

Comment: are you having this issue with some other excel file, with the same values? or is it just this particular file?

Comment: a similar issue http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/637277-excel-converting-numbers-dates.html

Answer (score 2):

you might want to check out a similar issue here:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/637277-excel-converting-numbers-dates.html

(the below suggestions might not be particularly relevant to this issue, but in general, they might help to resolve such a problem)

Selct the cells and go to `Format --> cells --> number` and select Text for the selection

There's also a one-keystroke solution: type an apostrophe before entering or pasting a pair of numbers that Excel could mistake for a date and month. When you exit the cell, the apostrophe vanishes and the numbers stay numbers, formatted as text.

this is what `microsoft` says:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-HA102809473.aspx

also if you are pasting data from somewhere else

try `Paste Special`

Comment: I'm sorry @gaurav5430, but i don't want change the cells format every time I open the file. And the link you posted, i've already seen but it seems this is not the point.

Comment: once saved, they will display as text only. but yes, for new cells you would have to change the format again. what about adding the apostrophe?

Comment: @pnuts , he is probably talking about integer numbers with hyphen or slash(for fractions) between them, so he is not directly using the cell as integers for any kind of integer calculations or something, so i guess it matters to him only that they display correctly

Comment: have a look at the microsoft link, in edited answer if it helps

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I have a file who worked fine until now without this issue. This file have some numbers columns (without formulas) and this numbers are integer numbers. Now, when I change the contents (insert new rows i.e.) and save and close the file, when I open again the numbers columns are in date format!...

Comment: Are you reluctant to use the apostrophe method or does it not work for you?

Comment: I can resolve the issue using apostrophe or changing cell format, but this is not my point. The point is understand why excel have a different behavior without having changed the assumptions. Why is that so far this has not happened and now unexplained started happening?

Comment: actually it is a known issue, it happens with everyone, and there are no settings provided in excel to turn this off. may be this never happened to you before because the input was never in such format. it happens with a lot of people a lot of times :) . please post the answer or workaround if you find.

Comment: ok, not this particular issue while saving, but yes conversion issue happens. also check http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/637277-excel-converting-numbers-dates.html

Comment: ok, so i may as well delete the answer, if this is what you would like, so that any future viewer who might have a similar query and who might be able to resolve the issue reading the answer/comments will also not be benefitted.

Comment: I believe the post mentioned might help, but how to know the format of the cells in tens of thousands of records? On the other hand, add a new information - this problem does not happen on all pcs...

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/excel-2007-spontaneously-formats-entire-work-book/1ae533af-ecee-41fa-866a-2590343a111d?auth=1 says you can change the cell styles were normal may for some reason be defaulting to date instead of general.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is still no solutions to this problem.

It happens in both my computers when inserting data from sql server 2008.

Half of columns becomes dates..... and im supposed to give this to my accountant.. sucks

(Btw i know about the special paste to text, then convert to number... but it takes so much time)....

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. I am using a webhook to store data to excel on the fly, adding new rows, updating existing data, etc.

I had a special field "step" which is a string who can be "1", "1.1", "1.2", etc. which was treated as date as soon as the value was a "string decimal"...

The only way I could find to fix this issue was to programmatically add a `'` before the value, like `'1.2`.

I tried to apply this to all my fields to avoid excel side effect, but I then noticed that when updating an existing row by merging new values with existing values then the `'` was stripped. So, I end up using a whitelist of fields to escape. I couldn't locate the fields to force adding `'` when merging data due to limitations from the lib I use `google-sheets-node-api`.